# Creating Custom Page Tab to Blogspot returns 405

Tags: facebook, blogspot

I'm trying to create a custom tab for a facebook page that links to a blogspot. The issue is that the url I use returns a 405. I see lots of posts that say the server should accept both http and https requests. I think blogspot does. What can I do to fix this?

For reference I followed this tutorial.

[Create Custom Tabs for Facebook Business](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/26330/How-to-Create-Custom-Tabs-for-Facebook-Business-Pages.aspx)

In the Editor's Note: It talks about my issue but advises to seek an experienced developer...

[image: My configuration]

Comment: So blog spot doesn't allow loading via post?

Comment: Nvm, you are right. I tried hitting the url on fiddler with a post. 405

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/TheTeacherNextDoor/ This page has apps that lead to webpages. How do they do that? It looks like it loads to another page that forwards them to the websites. How do they do that?